# Count the number of occurrences after associated date of certain value in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm conducting an exercise around examining test results after tutoring has occurred. Essentially looking at the rates of "pass" post tutoring within the context of a given student. Where the ultimate outcome would be:

pass rate after tutoring = [count passes]/[count test date] WHERE test date > tutoring date.

For example:

[image]

Ideally, the final output of the measure would be = 1 (1/1)

Would anyone be able to point me in the direction of achieving this through a Power BI measure?

I've attempted the following to get the single oc with no luck:

```
Measure 3 = CALCULATE(COUNT(Table[Test Pass?]),FILTER(Table,Table[Test Date]>CALCULATE(Min(Table[Tutoring Date]),FILTER(Table,Table[Tutor (?)] <> BLANK ))))
```

Where I would then use the student column in a matrix with the measure to group pass rates post tutoring by student

Comment: Poor selection of sample data that doesn't prove anything. And starting with crosstabs in Power BI creates hassle and any solution becomes unnecessarily cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this simple flat table data model:

[image]

You can calculate this with a measure that needs to be evaluated with your `Student` column:

```
Pass Rate After Tutoring =
VAR _tutor_date =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Tutoring Date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Student] )
    )
VAR _tests_post_tutor =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Student] ),
        'Table'[Test Date] > _tutor_date
    )
VAR _successes =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Student] ),
        'Table'[Test Date] > _tutor_date,
        'Table'[Test Pass]
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( _successes, _tests_post_tutor )
```

But this assumes that students are only tutored for one specific test, and are tutored once.